# Azure Data Factory unzip and move files

Tags: zip, azure-data-factory

I know this has been asked (in other question as well as) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57261025/how-to-decompress-a-zip-file-in-azure-data-factory-v2), which are exactly my cases. I have downloaded (via ADF) a zip file to Azure Blob and I am trying to decompress it and move the files to another location within the Azure Blob container.

However having tried both of those approaches I only end up with a zipped file moved to another location without it being unzipped.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand your question - Was your outcome a zip file or the folder name has .zip on it? It sounds crazy, let me explain in detail. In ADF decompressing the zip file using copy activity creates a folder(which has .zip on its name) which has actual file in it.

Example: Let's say you have sample.txt inside abc.zip

Blob sourcepath: container1/abc.zip [Here abc.zip is a compressed file]

Output path will be: container2/abc.zip/sample.txt [Here, abc.zip is the decompressed folder name]

This is achieved when the copy behaviour of sink is "none". Hope it helps :)

Comment: It doesn't unzip anything it just copies the blob over to a new location. There are 100's of files in that zip.

Comment: Can you just provide screenshots or detail information of what you have done? So it could be easy to resolve the issue

Comment: steps are exactly the same as in the linked issue

Comment: Yes, I agree your point but you might be missing something minimal. We should know the pipeline flow inorder to better understand and provide comments. Anyways, I'll provide you main items that should be done [source dataset: compression-ZipDeflate] [sink : copybehaviour-None, sink dataset : compression-None] rest all can be configured as per your requirements

Comment: I was able to do it by not downloading the file instead loading it straight from the source (without saving to Azure Blob storage). Once I did that the file was unzipped

Comment: @metase Just wanted to comment and say that this worked for me, too. For some reason when the source zip is already in Azure it will not decompress/unzip. When I switched my source to a self-hosted IR and pulled the zip directly into ADF from my file system it unzipped correctly.