# Merging multiple xml files to a csv file using azure Data Factory

Tags: xml, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have established a data factory pipeling to download zip file(open https linked source Url reference: https://clinicaltrials.gov/AllPublicXML.zip). Unzip the same files to a folder that has multiple files of xml format.[Copy and Extracting Zipped XML files from HTTP Link Source to Azure Blob Storage using Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65629115/copy-and-extracting-zipped-xml-files-from-http-link-source-to-azure-blob-storage/65644614#65644614) Now I want to merge all XML files in the folder to a CSV file. I am using copy activity inside the data factory. While importing schema I am getting the following error message

`Input XML file 'input/ALLPublicXML.zip' is invalid with parsing error 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. . Activity ID: 358b3545-f49c-4bba-8adc-13fb3de9bb20` [image]

Not exactly sure what is going wrong, but it would be really helpful if someone can guide me with the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an encoding issue, can you check the file once for encoding, it should follow the below encoding formats:

[image]

There might be some extra characters in file which are not allowing to read, more information can be found [here](https://www.ipreferjim.com/2014/09/data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1/)

Comment: Thanks, I am glad my answer helped, can you upvote it :)